# Protractor: get value of binding with xpath

Tags: angularjs, xpath, protractor, angularjs-e2e

If I have html like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="menu">
       <div id="button"> {{ someBinding }} </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and I have a statement in protractor like this:

```
ptor.findElement(By.xpath("/body/div[@id='menu']/div[@id='button']"));
```

What would I use to get the value of *{{someBinding}}*? It seems that protractor tries to compare the value with the binding name. So if I expect *{{someBinding}}* to say "Hello World" it throws an error saying that

```
Expected: {{someBinding}} to equal 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution if anyone else is looking for it. Adding to @rjferguson21 's answer, the expect line should look like this:

```
expect(el.evaluate("someBinding")).toBe("Hello World");
```

I think that was an update in Protractor.

Comment: i know this is a little old so maybe things have changed, but for me this didn't work i had to resolve the promise first, not sure why as usually expect auto resolves, but in case some one in the future is struggling with this, i thought id log my experience. so to clarify i had to do this; `el.evaluate("someBinding").then(function(bindingValue){ expect(bindingValue).toBe("Hello World)});`

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to call .getText() on the element.

`el = ptor.findElement(By.xpath("/body/div[@id='menu']/div[@id='button']"))`

so your entire statement would be:

`expect(el.getText()).toBe('Hello World');`

I would also consider using a different locator, such as the CSS locator if you are using ids, or have a look at the binding locator.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebelementprototypegettext
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#protractorbyprototypebinding

Comment: `element.getText()` throws an error so I remove the getText() method and it runs but I get the same error as I mentioned above. For my present project, the xpath method is the only locator that successfully retrieves my message.

Comment: I have updated my answer to try to be more clear, you need to call .getText() on the result of the findElement statement.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't have to use xpath selection for this. Try [binding](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#locators) locator:

```
var el = element(By.binding('someBinding'));
expect(el.getText()).toBe('Hello World');
```